# How to have columns which may contain several values in a dataframe print as [x, y] rather than c("x, "y") in R?

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I'm in RStudio and I have a dataframe containing multiple columns, some of which may contain 0, or more than 1 value per 1 record (1 line). Here is what the dataframe looks like:

[image]

When I try to `print()` this dataframe, I get the following result:

[image]

I'm supposed to have them show as this:

[image]

and I'm asked to *"Note that each record can also contain multiple UniProt IDs and groups, so these two columns need to store lists of values."*.

How can I do that (in as easy code as possible as I'm a close-to-total beginner)?

Thanks in advance

I tried the following:

```
df2$uniprot_ids <- map(df2$uniprot_ids, function(x) {
  if (is.list(x)) return(x) else return(list(x))
})
df2$uniprot_ids <- map_chr(df2$uniprot_ids, ~ paste(.x, collapse = ", "))


df2$gene_group <- map(df2$gene_group, function(x) {
  if (is.list(x)) return(x) else return(list(x))
})
df2$gene_group <- map_chr(df2$gene_group, ~ paste(.x, collapse = ", "))
```

Which then when I use `print()` gives the same display as in the first image above, but still not the one I expect.

Answer (score 1):

We may use

```
library(dplyr)
df2 %>%
    group_by(across(symbol:refseq)) %>%
    summarise(across(everything(), ~ list(.)))
```